# Can Anybody tell why the result is different between the following 2 codes?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
def find_words(num,string):
    a = re.findall('\w{int(num),}',string)
    return(a)
find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me")
```

**The output is []**

```
#####
import re
string = "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me"
a = re.findall('\w{4,}',string)
print(a)
```

**The output is ['baby', 'balloon']**

Comment: `int(num)` in a string literal isn't `4`. String literal contents aren't executed as Python code.

Comment: Maybe if you show the output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of your function that is supposed to be replaced with the input variable `num` won't work as posted because it's just a string.  You have to replace that part of the string first, like this:

```
import re

def find_words(num, string):
    target = '\w{%d,}' % num  # if num = 4, target becomes '\w{4,}'
    return re.findall(target, string)

print find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me")  # prints ['baby', 'balloon']
```

Alternatively, you could do this for the same result:

```
target = '\w{{{},}}'.format(num)
```

The double brackets are needed when using `format()` in order to include literal brackets in the string.